# WordPress blog in website (TYPO3)

Tags: wordpress, iframe, blogs, typo3

I've read quite a few posts asking which was the best way to integrate a blog developed in WordPress in a web site and for what I understood there are two alternatives.

In order to make a blog an element of my web site www.mysite.com/blog I have two choices:

1. Wrap the blog in a `<iframe>` and try to make it look as part of the
   web site as possible (handle templates,etc). The issue with this one
   is SEO, because as for what I understand SE won't parse the blog
   because it is within an iframe.
2. Install WordPress on the web site server and serve the page
       www.mysite.com/blog using the WordPress backend.

Now the thing is that the web site runs TYPO3 and I'd like to know which of these options is the best to make the user believe the blog is part of the web site.

Considering the TYPO3 varibale, are there better options?If not which one is better?

Comment: BTW: TYPO3's name is written with upper-case, always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the side by side version twice.

I finished one last week: blog.betreibungsschalter-plus.ch and www.betreibungsschalter-plus.ch. ( betreibungsschalter-plus.ch/blog was not possible, because the admin of the page was not able to configure apache that way, but it should work to)

Using TYPO3 as a blog is not recommended by me: the extensions are quite limited an you need several extension to come near wordpress features.

Downside of the side by side solution is that you have to double the navigation: If you change the navigation on the TYPO3 side you have to change it to on the wordpress side manually. (Or you hack wordpress to load the navigation from a TYPO3 Page)

Comment: Fabien, that's what I was trying to clarify: side-by-side is better, cause WP is champion in blogging software, and converting TYPO3 is just nervous. What's more WP brings new trends, TYPO3 extenion doesn't. On the other hand you do not to to reflect the whole navigation from TYPO3 in WP. it's enoght if you'll paste a big button, "Back to our site" - or something. It depends only on that if you know how to convince your client it's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the extension [realurl](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl/) you will get urls like example.com/contact/, example.com/whatever/ so it would be easy to create a subfolder "example.com/blog/" where you install wordpress to.

It is then only a matter of templating. I think the iframe thing is not helpful and more confusing.

Btw.: you can import via RSS the blog news as [tt_news](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tt_news/) records in TYPO3 (f.e. via [yafi](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/yafi/)). So you can teaser your blog posts on your website.

Comment: But can I add the blog as a content element in typo3? This way I would keep the wrapping menus and sub menus of the web site and have the blog in the middle, do you think that by installing word press it's the best way?

Comment: No, as you would operate both systems side-by-side, you'll have two seperate databases and two backends, e.g.: `www.mysite.com/typo3` for TYPO3 and `www.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin` for wordpress.

Comment: Oh, sorry, for the teaser function - yes, you would actually insert the `yafi` or the `tt_news` plugin as a CE.

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` approach isn't good that will be a `prosthesis solution`. On the other hand each blog is specialized application and even dedicated blog extensions for TYPO3 grabs almost whole instance very rapaciously. Must to say that TYPO3's extension are not good solution nowaday.

In such situation creating blog with dedicated `subdomain` or `subfolder` and operating it with WP backend is best option for this task.

Although TYPO3 is very good for many different tasks nobody said that has to do everything and I'm deeply believe that WP will be always better for blogging part.

Also nobody said that blog section has to be identical with CMS part. It will be enough if you'll use `coherent design` for both parts.

Comment: After installing wordpress on the server am I able to "decorate" the surrounding area of the blog so it's coherent with the rest of the site?

Comment: Well you can just use templates in TYPO3 and WordPress to make very similar design.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would rather recommend not to use two systems (Wordpress and typo3), because integrating WP into typo3 will always be not optimal. It'd be better to set-up the blog in typo3 right away, using an extension such as [T3BLOG](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3blog).

However, if you're stuck with two systems I see three ways how you can integrate your WP blog into a typo3 site

1. iFrame - as you mentioned. Not very recommended
2. RSS - Probaby the easierst solution. You simply configure WP to render you an RSS feed and then either import those entries into tt_news. Alternatively,  you can simply display the RSS feed on your site right away, using an extension such as [rss_display](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/rss_display) .
3. The last option is to directly include the HTML output of Wordpress into your site. One way to do this is using the [fetchURL](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fetchurl) typo3 extension. You however need to be cautious that this does not mess up your HTML markup. In addition, I don't know if functions like commenting in WP will still work. But surely worth a try!